# save twitter user information into a file using StreamListener

Tags: python, json, twitter, tweepy, twitter-streaming-api

Guys i wanna save twitter user info like name, statuses, tweet in my file (either json,txt,csv or any other json or text are prefered). I tried this code and some other similar but none of them work. Guys have a look at below code and suggest me what changes should i made??

```
import time
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
import os
import json

ckey = '**********'
consumer_secret = '**********'
access_token_key = '**********'
access_token_secret = '**********'

start_time = time.time() #grabs the system time
keyword_list = ['twitter'] #track list

#Listener Class Override
class listener(StreamListener):

    def __init__(self, start_time, time_limit=60):

        self.time = start_time
        self.limit = time_limit

    def on_data(self, data):

        while (time.time() - self.time) < self.limit:
            try:
                all_data = json.loads["text"]
                username = all_data["user"]["name"]
                tweets = all_date["user"]["statuses"]
                saveFile = open('raw_tweets29.json', 'a')
                saveFile.write(username)
                saveFile.write('\n')
                saveFile.close()

                return True
            except BaseException, e:
                print 'failed ondata,', str(e)
                time.sleep(5)
                pass
        exit()

    def on_error(self, status):
        print statuses

auth = OAuthHandler(ckey, consumer_secret) #OAuth object
auth.set_access_token(access_token_key, access_token_secret)
twitterStream = Stream(auth, listener(start_time, time_limit=20))
twitterStream.filter(track=['twitter'])
```

when i run below code this give me error -
`failed ondata, 'function' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`

I would greatly appreciate any help you can give me in working this problem

Comment: I would recommend you not to include your keys in the question. Also, your try, except section is covering too many commands. Try to reduce it so you can debug it properly.

Comment: Which Python version are you using?

Comment: i am using 2.7.3, execption might be because of try block

Comment: FYI - I reproduced the error but the code looks right. Then tried modifying it for python 3 but when running it ran into a known bug where the stream buffer returns bytes but is initialized with a string. Perhaps try a different API such as twython (https://github.com/ryanmcgrath/twython) which Joel Grus demoed in his book Data Science From Scratch, see code at https://github.com/joelgrus/data-science-from-scratch/blob/master/code/getting_data.py#L97

Comment: can you update exact trace of the error.

Comment: @AshwaniAgarwal i figure it out, anyway thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am doing some mistake, now i figure it out there is no need of temp variable 'text' what i need to do is load actual data.
there is one more thing require is encoding.
thanks everyone for your time.

```
import time
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
import os,sys
import json

ckey = '***'
consumer_secret = '***'
access_token_key = '***'
access_token_secret = '***'

start_time = time.time()

class listener(StreamListener):

    def __init__(self, start_time, time_limit=300):

        self.time = start_time
        self.limit = time_limit

    def on_data(self, data):

        while (time.time() - self.time) < self.limit:
            try:
                tweet = json.loads(data)
                user_name = tweet['user']['name']
                tweet_count = tweet['user']['statuses_count']
                text = tweet['text']
                saveFile = open('user_tweets29.json', 'a')
                saveFile.write(text.encode('utf8'))
                saveFile.write('\n')
                saveFile.close()

                return True
            except BaseException, e:
                print 'failed ondata,', str(e)
                time.sleep(5)
                pass
        exit()

    def on_error(self, status):
        print statuses

auth = OAuthHandler(ckey, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token_key, access_token_secret)
twitterStream = Stream(auth, listener(start_time, time_limit=60))
twitterStream.filter(track=['twitter'])
```